# My ADSL router keeps disconnecting, how can I diagnose it?

Tags: networking, router, adsl

My ADSL router (a 10-ish years old Comtrend AR-5381u) keeps disconnecting from the Internet every few minutes. It's been like that for 3-4 days; the weird thing is that it only happens during the evenings.

I have tried rebooting the router from the software admin console (it doesn't help), and physically turning it off and on again (for the previous days, it solved the problem... today it didn't).

I have WiFi enabled (WPA2-PSK + AES, and MAC filtering). Not sure if that's secure enough, but anyway I'm checking the "WiFi authenticated devices" and the only one shown is my own phone, so it's not a bored neighbour messing up with my WiFi.

Also, I'm not running any P2P software, nor doing anything that could *break the Internet*. Just a couple open tabs in Google Chrome, and a few background apps in the phone. Other times I'm just watching Netflix or Youtube on my TV, no computer at all.

**What could I do (if anything) to solve or at least diagnose the problem?**

I don't even know if it's my router, or the ISP, or somebody taking my connection down (DDoS? It's not like I'm Microsoft, it's just my home...).

Here is the system log since the last (physical) reboot. There are a lot of "kernel intrussions", but from what I've read, I shouldn't worry about them, they're just *attempts* to access my router from the Internet (or aren't they?).

```
Jan 1 00:00:08  syslog  emerg   BCM96345 started: BusyBox v1.00 (2011.10.28-05:10+0000)
Jan 1 00:00:24  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: xDSL G.994 training
Jan 1 00:00:24  user    crit    kernel: eth0 Link UP 100 mbps full duplex
Jan 1 00:00:37  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 started
Jan 1 00:00:41  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 channel analysis
Jan 1 00:00:45  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 message exchange
Jan 1 00:00:46  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL link down
Jan 1 00:00:47  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: xDSL G.994 training
Jan 1 00:01:00  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 started
Jan 1 00:01:04  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 channel analysis
Jan 1 00:01:08  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 message exchange
Jan 1 00:01:10  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL link up, Bearer 0, us=842, ds=16590
Jan 1 00:01:34  daemon  crit    syslog: PPP server detected.
Jan 1 00:01:34  daemon  crit    syslog: PPP session established.
Jan 1 00:01:40  daemon  crit    syslog: PPP LCP UP.
Jan 1 00:03:22  daemon  crit    syslog: PPP server detected.
Jan 1 00:03:23  daemon  crit    syslog: PPP session established.
Jan 1 00:03:26  daemon  crit    syslog: PPP LCP UP.
Jan 1 00:03:26  daemon  crit    syslog: Received valid IP address from server. Connection UP.
Apr 7 20:30:00  user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=77.72.82.94 DST=95.16.160.53 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=244 ID=20107 PROTO=TCP SPT=41720 DPT=8859 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Apr 7 20:30:00  user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=46.161.55.108 DST=95.16.160.53 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=243 ID=19005 PROTO=TCP SPT=43447 DPT=2443 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Apr 7 20:30:01  user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=5.188.11.37 DST=95.16.160.53 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=244 ID=38893 PROTO=TCP SPT=55797 DPT=5389 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Apr 7 20:30:29  user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=59.38.100.155 DST=95.16.160.53 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=241 ID=61313 PROTO=TCP SPT=58121 DPT=1433 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Apr 7 20:30:45  user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=223.100.148.74 DST=95.16.160.53 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=233 ID=33541 PROTO=TCP SPT=45265 DPT=1433 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Apr 7 20:40:01  user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=50.2.190.138 DST=95.16.160.53 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=243 ID=8313 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=18013 DPT=1250 WINDOW=512 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Apr 7 20:50:07  user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=185.216.140.16 DST=95.16.160.53 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=243 ID=23593 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=32210 DPT=3308 WINDOW=512 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Apr 7 21:00:03  user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=211.152.60.146 DST=95.16.160.53 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=110 ID=256 PROTO=TCP SPT=49268 DPT=445 WINDOW=16384 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Apr 7 21:02:01  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL link down
Apr 7 21:02:01  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: xDSL G.994 training
Apr 7 21:02:01  daemon  crit    syslog: Clear IP addresses. PPP connection DOWN.
Apr 7 21:02:01  daemon  crit    syslog: Clear IP addresses. Connection DOWN.
Apr 7 21:02:13  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 started
Apr 7 21:02:17  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 channel analysis
Apr 7 21:02:21  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 message exchange
Apr 7 21:02:22  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL link down
Apr 7 21:02:23  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: xDSL G.994 training
Apr 7 21:02:36  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 started
Apr 7 21:02:40  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 channel analysis
Apr 7 21:02:44  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 message exchange
Apr 7 21:02:45  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL link up, Bearer 0, us=888, ds=17075
Apr 7 21:03:12  daemon  crit    syslog: PPP server detected.
Apr 7 21:03:12  daemon  crit    syslog: PPP session established.
Apr 7 21:03:15  daemon  crit    syslog: PPP LCP UP.
Apr 7 21:03:17  daemon  crit    syslog: Received valid IP address from server. Connection UP.
Apr 7 21:03:28  user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=185.216.140.16 DST=95.16.58.57 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=242 ID=29519 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=17817 DPT=3729 WINDOW=512 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Apr 7 21:04:07  user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=5.188.11.37 DST=95.16.58.57 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=245 ID=44709 PROTO=TCP SPT=55797 DPT=3382 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Apr 7 21:04:21  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL link down
Apr 7 21:04:21  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: xDSL G.994 training
Apr 7 21:04:21  daemon  crit    syslog: Clear IP addresses. PPP connection DOWN.
Apr 7 21:04:21  daemon  crit    syslog: Clear IP addresses. Connection DOWN.
Apr 7 21:04:33  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 started
Apr 7 21:04:37  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 channel analysis
Apr 7 21:04:42  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 message exchange
Apr 7 21:04:43  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL link down
Apr 7 21:04:44  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: xDSL G.994 training
Apr 7 21:04:56  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 started
Apr 7 21:05:00  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 channel analysis
Apr 7 21:05:05  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 message exchange
Apr 7 21:05:06  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL link up, Bearer 0, us=888, ds=16380
Apr 7 21:05:30  daemon  crit    syslog: PPP server detected.
Apr 7 21:05:30  daemon  crit    syslog: PPP session established.
Apr 7 21:05:33  daemon  crit    syslog: PPP LCP UP.
Apr 7 21:05:34  daemon  crit    syslog: Received valid IP address from server. Connection UP.
Apr 7 21:06:08  user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=109.248.9.18 DST=87.218.25.144 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=243 ID=38071 PROTO=TCP SPT=50193 DPT=51391 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Apr 7 21:06:36  user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=185.216.140.16 DST=87.218.25.144 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=243 ID=50787 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=50400 DPT=4509 WINDOW=512 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Apr 7 21:06:45  user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=139.162.115.7 DST=87.218.25.144 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=241 ID=54321 PROTO=TCP SPT=58362 DPT=110 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Apr 7 21:06:58  user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=185.130.212.2 DST=87.218.25.144 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=243 ID=56833 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=2 DPT=8034 WINDOW=512 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Apr 7 21:07:18  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL link down
Apr 7 21:07:18  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: xDSL G.994 training
Apr 7 21:07:19  daemon  crit    syslog: Clear IP addresses. PPP connection DOWN.
Apr 7 21:07:19  daemon  crit    syslog: Clear IP addresses. Connection DOWN.
Apr 7 21:07:30  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 started
Apr 7 21:07:34  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 channel analysis
Apr 7 21:07:39  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 message exchange
Apr 7 21:07:40  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL link down
Apr 7 21:07:41  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: xDSL G.994 training
Apr 7 21:07:53  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 started
Apr 7 21:07:57  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 channel analysis
Apr 7 21:08:02  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 message exchange
Apr 7 21:08:03  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL link up, Bearer 0, us=888, ds=16847
Apr 7 21:08:27  daemon  crit    syslog: PPP server detected.
Apr 7 21:08:27  daemon  crit    syslog: PPP session established.
Apr 7 21:08:30  daemon  crit    syslog: PPP LCP UP.
Apr 7 21:08:31  daemon  crit    syslog: Received valid IP address from server. Connection UP.
Apr 7 21:09:07  user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=185.222.211.90 DST=87.218.24.53 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=244 ID=3613 PROTO=TCP SPT=53518 DPT=33392 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Apr 7 21:09:15  user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=185.216.140.16 DST=87.218.24.53 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=243 ID=11129 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=6335 DPT=4869 WINDOW=512 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Apr 7 21:09:27  user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=181.214.87.248 DST=87.218.24.53 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=244 ID=33982 PROTO=TCP SPT=46326 DPT=3389 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Apr 7 21:09:39  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL link down
Apr 7 21:09:39  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: xDSL G.994 training
Apr 7 21:09:39  daemon  crit    syslog: Clear IP addresses. PPP connection DOWN.
Apr 7 21:09:39  daemon  crit    syslog: Clear IP addresses. Connection DOWN.
Apr 7 21:09:51  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 started
Apr 7 21:09:55  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 channel analysis
Apr 7 21:10:00  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 message exchange
Apr 7 21:10:01  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL link down
Apr 7 21:10:02  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: xDSL G.994 training
Apr 7 21:10:14  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 started
Apr 7 21:10:18  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 channel analysis
Apr 7 21:10:23  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 message exchange
Apr 7 21:10:24  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL link up, Bearer 0, us=888, ds=16953
Apr 7 21:10:48  daemon  crit    syslog: PPP server detected.
Apr 7 21:11:18  daemon  crit    syslog: PPP session established.
Apr 7 21:11:21  daemon  crit    syslog: PPP LCP UP.
Apr 7 21:11:22  daemon  crit    syslog: Received valid IP address from server. Connection UP.
Apr 7 21:11:51  user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=77.72.82.103 DST=95.16.175.33 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=245 ID=20005 PROTO=TCP SPT=54206 DPT=49 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Apr 7 21:12:09  user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=185.216.140.16 DST=95.16.175.33 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=243 ID=37390 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=18182 DPT=4929 WINDOW=512 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Apr 7 21:12:41  user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=141.105.71.116 DST=95.16.175.33 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=243 ID=55831 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=12970 DPT=8091 WINDOW=512 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Apr 7 21:12:44  user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=189.211.6.43 DST=95.16.175.33 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=114 ID=27155 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=61195 DPT=445 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Apr 7 21:12:52  user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=5.101.2.205 DST=95.16.175.33 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=243 ID=38539 PROTO=TCP SPT=47669 DPT=3426 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Apr 7 21:13:37  user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=5.188.11.43 DST=95.16.175.33 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=244 ID=23727 PROTO=TCP SPT=47504 DPT=4049 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Apr 7 21:13:42  user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=77.72.82.88 DST=95.16.175.33 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=245 ID=6796 PROTO=TCP SPT=59153 DPT=3222 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Apr 7 21:13:44  user    alert   kernel: Intrusion -> IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=93.174.93.218 DST=95.16.175.33 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=244 ID=22819 PROTO=TCP SPT=46685 DPT=20183 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 MARK=0x8000000
Apr 7 21:13:59  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL link down
Apr 7 21:13:59  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: xDSL G.994 training
Apr 7 21:13:59  daemon  crit    syslog: Clear IP addresses. PPP connection DOWN.
Apr 7 21:13:59  daemon  crit    syslog: Clear IP addresses. Connection DOWN.
Apr 7 21:14:11  user    crit    kernel: Line 0: ADSL G.992 started
```

It seems like the line goes down shortly after there are a few "intrussions"... each time. So maybe it's some sort of attack taking it down, or at least making the router unresponsive so that it loses the connection. Can I somehow protect it from this?

**Update**:

I unplugged all the phones, and connected the router directly to the wall socket. It improved slightly, but it still keeps disconnecting.

The router statistics show a SNR margin of around 9dB whenever the connection goes up, and then it drops. Sometimes it keeps at 8 or 7, sometimes it drops to 5, 4, 3dB... The lowest I've seen it is 1.9. Sometimes it goes back up to 7, other times the connection is lost. Both downstream and upstream fluctuate like that, but downstream is usually lower. My connection is "up to 20Mbps download and up to 1Mbps upload", so I guess the upstream is not "as crowded".

Other thing I've noticed is that I have an insane number of HEC errors, mostly downstream. Like 5000 new errors every 15 seconds. And that's when the line is actually up and working...

Here is an screenshot of the statistics page right now. 1.8 million HEC errors... since the last reboot 8 hours ago:

[image]

Comment: Might be time for a new router or a firmware upgrade if available.

Comment: Call your ISP first before trying anything else. It looks like there may be an issue with your ADSL connection.

Comment: A decade is an incredible amount of time for that to be running. Does your modem show SNR readings?

Comment: It shows "SNR margin", it starts around 9dB when it reconnects, then falls to somewhere around 3dB, and then the connection is lost. By the way it's 8 in the morning and the problem keeps happening, even worse than in the previous days. I guess the problem is a very noisy line on the ISP's end?

Comment: If you have access to your side of the wiring, it's never a bad idea to try and troubleshoot inside wiring. If you have any other phones or equipment on that line disconnect them when you troubleshoot. Sometimes it can be a faulty handset etc.

Comment: 3db of SNR is a very low level, and sounds like the reason of it disconnecting. That may be just a rusty connection, loose cable or a number of other things. If you have inside cabling, you may want to test the line attaching at the demarc, or w/o the phone and filters.

Comment: CRC, FEC and HEC errors usually indicate noise problems on the line. See [::. Kitz - Linestat parameters & counters .::](http://www.kitz.co.uk/adsl/linestats_errors.htm)  for more info.

Comment: [HEC Errors Router](https://mybroadband.co.za/vb/showthread.php/571313-HEC-Errors-Router)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As most of the comments said, it was a problem on the line. Or it must have been, because it's solved now and I didn't change anything :). I was waiting until monday to call my ISP's customer service, but apparently they fixed the issue that same monday. The Internet connection hasn't dropped since then, and it's been 4 days already.

The SNR (signal-to-noise ratio) margin is much much better and stable now: 12-14 dB downstream and 9 dB upstream, anything over 6dB is good enough, so no problems there.

I still have HEC errors<sup>[1](https://mybroadband.co.za/vb/showthread.php/571313-HEC-Errors-Router) [2](http://www.kitz.co.uk/adsl/linestats_errors.htm)</sup>, but now they're in the order of 5.000 per hour, instead of 225.000.

As for the "kernel intrusion" alerts, they still show up in the router's log from time to time, but the line keeps working, so it's clear they weren't the issue. Maybe they didn't help though, with a router already struggling so much with the extremely noisy line.

---

**Update**: just a follow-up to confirm that it was, in fact, the line. The problems have started again, and after calling my ISP a few times, they have sent me a brand new router... which keeps losing the connection, even if I plug it directly to the "network termination" test port instead of the regular phone plugs. In fact, it's handling the noise even worse than my ancient router. Time to go digital and get an optical fiber line instead of the DSL.

Comment: I'm keen on finding what causes this as of being infected with the same problem.

Comment: Mahdi, in my case it was a poor line quality from the ISP node to my house. Eventually I gave up and switched from DSL to optical fiber. Best decision ever.

Answer (score 1):

You may be experiencing more than one problem. Those are always the hardest to find and fix. I speak from being a Transmission and Maintenance Engineer for VZ for 30 years. First, S/N should always be a "big" number. You want lots of signal and no noise. When the signal diminishes and starts to approach the noise, their fractional ratio (S/N) starts getting closer to one. As a rule thumb (for DSL) less than 10db is bad. For measurements of 11db to 20db is okay but, not great. S/N more than 20db is what you want. Things that affect your signal strength are distance from the TelCo's serving node and multiple appearances of your cable pair. They're called "Bridge Taps" or "Left-Ins" and add unnecessarily to the cable pair's capacitance. Ask the company to get rid of them. If anyone suggests there may be "Load Coils", they are wrong. You can't get any digital signal through a load coil. You have a 18Kft cable pair distance limitation from the TelCo's node. At that point the cable pairs inherent capacitance will diminish the signal to the point where it's unusable. Load coils are use for the voice frequency spectrum (300 - 3000 Hz) only and you won't have them on cable pairs under 18 Kft. The other half of the S/N is the noise component. The noise comes in the form of wet cable pairs, poor tip/ring splices and old cable pairs breaking down. Ask the tech for tip/gnd, ring/gnd, tip/ring resistance and voltage measurements. Don't over look the in-house wiring. Don't run the inside wire from phone jack to jack to jack. Try using an inside wire directly to your TelCo's Network Interface. On your gateway router, you should have several LEDs. Look at the DSL LED. It should not be flashing ... ever. If it does flash or is extinguished, the Gateway router has "lost sight" of the serving node and may be trying to retrain. If the ISP or internet LED is flashing or is extinguished, that's a problem in the TelCo's serving node. It could be a Central Office or a neighborhood pair gain cabinet. Helpful hints, Take your "good quality" telephone off hook, you will be connected to a touch tone receiver in the serving node. You will hear dial tone. Stop the dial tone by pushing any digit on the dial. Cover your mouth piece and just listen. You should hear nothing (no noise). If you do, ask for a clean cable pair to diminish the noise. I'm certain you have a DSL filter. They cut the high frequency tone off your telephone set. Twice in my life, I've seen them short out and fail. If you have any doubt, just remove it for testing. Pay particular attention to your Gateway/Router "System Logs". They're always good for a clue. Don't be too hard on the TelCo Techs. Most Techs and Engineers are there by appointment and not for their educational background and skills. In my 30 years, I would trust only 6 or 8 people for their knowledge and ability to fix technical issues. There's a whole lot more but this is not the time or place. Good Luck, Dave